# How to create web installer?

Tags: web

How to create installer that is smaller than original app in size.
At the time of installation it downloads all files from the internet to install on PC.
I read several articles, watched the video, but there it is all about viruses. I'm not going to create spyware or malware. I mean installer like Google Chrome web installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create such installers using the program [GetWebInstaller](https://www.getwebinstaller.com/). Creates a small-sized installer

Comment: Can you add some details as to why the suggested program meets the requirements?

Comment: The web-installer, made by getwebinstaller uses windows api, it has a small size, which ensures fast loading.

Answer (score 1):

You can create [clickonce](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment?view=vs-2017) deployment if you are developing your application over Microsoft technologies. There are 3 strategies available for clickonce deployment:

- Install from Web
- Install from CD
- Start from Web

This youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4BTLdIMYEY) could also help.